# How should I add checkbox in UI5 sap.m.Dialog

Tags: sapui5

Currently the  sap.m.Dialog only have the addButton method which can only add Button control, I just want to add the checkbox in the dialog footer like "Don not show this dialog again"

Comment: on https://launchpad.support.sap.com after login open one Dialog with this, they use a litte bit of css to do.

Comment: Thanks for your help that exactly what I want, currently research how did they css on that. But I just do a simple test use F12 to simulate the phone mode, the footer is crash.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Update:** as of [commit `cc55b10`](https://github.com/SAP/openui5/commit/cc55b10c9df3682e88a6273714db1d76a8d2290d) (available in UI5 1.110), `sap.m.Dialog` comes with the new `footer` aggregation which awaits an instance of `sap.m.Toolbar`. There, you can add anything you want such as the `sap.m.CheckBox`.

---

#### For UI5 version lower than 1.110 (previous answer):

Adding a checkbox to the dialog footer is currently not supported as the corresponding aggregations `<buttons>`, `<endButton>`, and `<beginButton>` all await only `sap.m.Button` (or controls derived form it). I filed an [enhancement request on GitHub](https://github.com/SAP/openui5/issues/2018) in case you're interested.

The closest solution I could think of right now is to add ...:

- [`sap.m.ToggleButton`](https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/sample/sap.m.sample.ToggleButton/preview) with the toggle text <kbd>Don't Show This Again</kbd>, or
- `sap.m.Button` with the text <kbd>Close And Don't Show This Again</kbd>

... next to a normal close button.

Comment: thanks for help, I also check the sap.ui library, the dialog footer aggregations can contains control

Comment: @吴晓伟 Do you mean the [sap.ui.commons.Dialog](https://ui5.sap.com/index_v1.html#test-resources/sap/ui/commons/demokit/Dialog.html)? Unfortunately, the `sap.ui.commons` is not only deprecated but also [incompatible with `sap.m` library](https://ui5.sap.com/#/topic/363cd16eba1f45babe3f661f321a7820).

Comment: @吴晓伟 There might be a [feature coming](https://github.com/SAP/openui5/issues/2012#issuecomment-385328042) where we can define our own footer. As soon as it lands on the stable branch, I'll update my answer.

Comment: Yes, you're correct, sap.ui.commons. waiting for your good news, thanks

Comment: @吴晓伟 Updated the answer with the "good news" ;)